# Show textarea or div (just below the comment to reply),when i click reply button on comment system javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript, php, comments, system

So i am trying to make a comment system in my new site.All the comments have a reply button with id '**replybtn**' which, onclick i want to show a textarea or input field inside a div with id '**replyform**' right below the respective comment. And i am using php,mysql to retrieve comments.

```
<div class='cmt'>
    <div class='cmttext'></div>
    <div id='replybtn'></div>
    <div id='replyform'>
       <form method='post' ..... >
          <textarea name='reply' ></textarea>
          <input type='submit' />
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you. This is my first question asked on stackoverflow, so sorry if i have not given sufficient information.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It is plain JavaScript. Modify below what you want. :)
I updated it.

```js
var varHtml = "<form method='post' ..... ><textarea name='reply' ></textarea> <input type='submit' /> </form>";


var allElements = document.body.getElementsByClassName("replybtn");

var addCommentField = function() {
  for (var i = 0; allElements.length > i; i++) {
    if (allElements[i] === this) {
      console.log("this " + i);

      if (document.getElementsByClassName("replyform")[i].innerHTML.length === 0) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("replyform")[i].innerHTML = varHtml;
      }

    }
  }
};


for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
  allElements[i].addEventListener('click', addCommentField, false);
}
```

```html
<div class='cmt'>
  <div class='cmttext'></div>
  <button class='replybtn'>replybtn</button>
  <div class='replyform'></div>
</div>
<div class='cmt'>
  <div class='cmttext'></div>
  <button class='replybtn'>replybtn</button>
  <div class='replyform'></div>
</div>
<div class='cmt'>
  <div class='cmttext'></div>
  <button class='replybtn'>replybtn</button>
  <div class='replyform'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey its working bro, thank you but it has more than one comment, so it also has more than one reply button  and it is only working on first comment.

Comment: Should i use replybtn as class instead of id?

Comment: Thanks a ton Iv0gun9. This is exactly what i need. Thank you so much :)